# does InfluxDB support RestAPI

Tags: rest, influxdb

I am using InfluxDB to collect timeseries data. Does InfluxDB support RestAPI ? if not, how to configure REST for InfluxDB?

AK

Answer (score 2):

Yes, InfluxDB provides a REST API. You can see its reference here:

[API reference](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/tools/api/)

You may also want to check:

- [Writing Data with the HTTP API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/guides/writing_data/)
- [Querying Data with the HTTP API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/guides/querying_data/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done through the command line as indicated above,
Another nice and easy option, is to use the web-based admin interface (usually listen at port 8083).
You can write the query at the web page, and generate the REST call through the "Generate Query URL" button.
Here is an example for my generated query: http://myserver.com:8086/query?q=select+*+from+myteable&db=mydb

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Look at the following codes:

```
def write(self, data, params=None, expected_response_code=204,
          protocol='json'):

    headers = self._headers
    headers['Content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream'

    if params:
        precision = params.get('precision')
    else:
        precision = None

    if protocol == 'json':
        data = make_lines(data, precision).encode('utf-8')
    elif protocol == 'line':
        data = ('\n'.join(data) + '\n').encode('utf-8')

    self.request(
        url="write",
        method='POST',
        params=params,
        data=data,
        expected_response_code=expected_response_code,
        headers=headers
    )
    return True
```

This function is the implementation how influxdb-python write data into influxdb.We create a dict like:
{"measurement": "xxx", "tags":{...}, "fields":{...}, "time":...}
and then it will be transformed to a restful request by influxdb-python module.